# Execute psexec using service in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2005

I need execute a program in the remote computer, so I created a **service** in order to call psexec (it's crucial using the service). However, this service cannot call psexec.

Following the code:

```
            String cmd = "", arguments = "";
            cmd = @"C:\PsTools\psexec.exe";

            arguments = @"\\remoteComputer -u "user" -p "password" "C:\program.exe"";

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            process.Start();
            result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            sError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            result += "Program has finished its execution";
```

Do anyone know why the service cannot call the psexec?

Comment: Is the call to psexec just "hanging" ?

Comment: the service must run with privileges allowing access to this directory. an service is also running, when NO user is logged on.

Comment: No error. Seems the service waits forever. The log file don't show the any message (in this case, result and sError)

Comment: @nabuchodonossor: I'm logged and I'm administrator.

Comment: @Brandon Moretz: The service needs to wait the remote program response.

Comment: @Jannibelli the first time a user runs psexec they get a blocking dialog that they must click "Ok" on. Have you logged into the machine as your "service account" and manually executed psexec at least once?

Comment: @Moretz: Yes. I can use this method above in the windows application, but the windows service not. Is there any property that I need set to it works in the windows service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had issues with psexec hanging too when running a batch file remotely. How about WMI? This worked for me when running something on a remote computer; it works for *.bat and *.exe too. You might need to click Project>Add Reference and choose "System.Management" on the .NET tab--the reference wasn't there in VS 2010 until I manually added it.

```
        System.Management.ConnectionOptions connOptions =
            new System.Management.ConnectionOptions();

        connOptions.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;

        string compName = "RemoteComputerName";
        System.Management.ManagementScope manScope =
            new System.Management.ManagementScope(
                String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", compName), connOptions);
        manScope.Connect();

        System.Management.ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions =
            new System.Management.ObjectGetOptions();

        System.Management.ManagementPath managementPath =
            new System.Management.ManagementPath("Win32_Process");

        System.Management.ManagementClass processClass =
            new System.Management.ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);

        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject inParams =
            processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

        inParams["CommandLine"] = @"c:\MyBatchFile.bat";

        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject outParams =
            processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `psexec` as a user with `Administrator` permissions to the remote computer. (All the `-u` option does is to change the account used to execute the command on the remote computer.) Either configure your service to run as an account with permissions to the remote computer, or use a second instance of `psexec` to run the first instance of `psexec` as the appropriate user.